# Non-measurability of a set (Outer Measure)

Tags: real-analysis

**Suppose that E ⊂ [0,1] and E is not measurable.  Show that 
m*(E) + m*([0,1] - E) > 1**.

I found a similar relation here; however, I am having difficulty understanding how to show this relationship.  Any guidance would be helpful.
http://math.bard.edu/belk/math461/NonMeasurableSets.pdf

Comment: Are you assuming that $E$ is a Vitali set, or are you only assuming it is non-measurable?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $E$ is Vitalli. Let show that $m^*([0,1]\backslash E)=1$. Since $E$ is non-measurable, $m^*(E)>0$, and thus, we'll have $$m^*(E\backslash [0,1])+m^*(E)>1.$$ 
Suppose by contradiction that $m^*(E)<1$. Then, there is an open set $\mathcal O\supset E$ s.t. $m(\mathcal O)<1$. In particular, $A:=[0,1]\backslash \mathcal O\subset E$ and $m(A)>0$. We know that $\{E+q\}_{q\in \mathbb Q\cap [-1,1]}$ are disjoints (see lemma 3 of your link). Therefore,
$$3=m([-1,2])\geq m\left(\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb Q\cap [-1,1]}E+q\right)=\sum_{q\in \mathbb Q\cap[-1,1]}m(E+q)=\sum_{q\in\mathbb Q\cap [-1,1]}m(E)=\infty ,$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore $m^*([0,1]\backslash E)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

The outer measure of a set is defined as:
$$
m^*(E) = \inf\Bigg\{ \sum_{i=1}^n l(I_i) : E \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i \Bigg\}.
$$

Now, it is clear that $m^*(E) + m^*([0,1] \backslash E) \geq m^*([0,1])$, because if the intervals $I_i$ cover $E$ and the intervals $J_i$ cover $[0,1] \backslash E$, then $\{I_i\} \cup \{J_i\}$ cover $[0,1]$, hence every cover of $E$ and $[0,1] \backslash E$ also covers $[0,1]$, so $m^*(E) + m^*([0,1] \backslash E) \geq m^*([0,1])$.

Now, if $E$ were measurable, then by the definition of being measurable, $m(E) + m([0,1] \backslash E) = m([0,1])$. Since $E$ is not measurable, it follows that $$m^*(E) + m^*([0,1] \backslash E) > m^*([0,1]) = 1$$.

Comment: @Surb This is the definition of Jordan outer measure that I have used. The point is, the infimum need not be attained at all. It's possible that as we approach the infimum, the number of intervals required for such a cover gets larger and larger. The infimum itself need not be attained through a finite cover of open intervals, instead every number bigger than the infimum should be attained using finitely many open intervals. That's why this definition makes sense. You can probably read up the definition somewhere it is the same.

Comment: Thank you! The clarification helps me understand the theory.